# Can't load same name readonly virtual environment variable to python virtual environment

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, python-venv

I'm trying to understand this behavior:

In a bash script I set a variable as readonly as I use it in multiple sections:

```
readonly PROJECT_PATH="project/dir/path"
```

In a different section I add it to a .env file that different submodules will make use of

```
setup_submodule() {
  local proj_path="$PROJECT_PATH"
  local env_path=".env"

  if [[ "$CLEAN" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Remove ${env_path}"
    rm -rf "$env_path"
  fi
  if [[ -e "${env_path}" ]]; then
    echo "File ${env_path} exists, nothing to do"
    return 0
  fi
  cat <<EOF > "$env_path"
# common
export PROJECT_PATH=${proj_path} # Same name as the variable defined in the script!!!
export RUN_DIRECTORY=.
EOF
```

This previous part was working fine.

In a different section I'm creating a virtual environment, and I want to also load it with different environmental variables (towards the end):

```
setup_python_venv() {
  local env_path=".env" # RELEVANT
  

  if [[ ! -d "$PYTHON_VENV" ]]; then
    echo "Create python venv with '${PYTHON_BIN}' to '${PYTHON_VENV}' and update pip to latest version"
    "$PYTHON_BIN" -m venv "$PYTHON_VENV"
    (
      source "${PYTHON_VENV}/bin/activate"
      pip install -U pip
    )
  else
    echo "Python venv '${PYTHON_VENV}' already exists, nothing to do"
  fi
  echo "Install python dependencies"
  (
    source "${PYTHON_VENV}/bin/activate"
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  )
  echo "source $env_path" >> "${PYTHON_VENV}/bin/activate" # RELEVANT
  return 0
}
```

But in this case I get `PROJECT_PATH: readonly variable`

The code works if I change PROJECT_PATH name so that it's not the same name variable that is exported into .env. Still, I'm not entirely sure why it works when I first laod it into the file .env, but it then fails when loading it into the virtual environment.

Comment: I do not understand what is happening in order. `In a bash script I set a variable as readonly` Ok, you set it. `In a different section I add it to a .env file that different submodules will make use of` I do not know what is a "submodule", must be an internal name _you_ use to structure your code. The presented code creates a file `.env` (where?). `when I first laod it into the file .env` What does it "load into"? When you _write_ to file, you can write anything. When you `source .env`, the variable is set, it is readonly, hence the error.

Comment: I'm sorry, by submodule I meant a git Submodule declared previously in the project. It's just a subfolder, which will later diggest the .env file.

- `The presented code creates a file .env (where?)`: The .env file is created at the root of the folder. 
- `What does it "load into"?`: I meant it will jsut contain `export PROJECT_PATH=project/dir/path`.
- `When you source .env, the variable is set, it is readonly, hence the error`: Gotcha.

Comment: So re-naming the variable would be the only way to make use of it in the `source .env`?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can just remove `readonly`. You can check if the variable is set, and only set it then. You can unset the variable before loading. Overall, setting variable from python env sounds odd for me.

Comment: Thanks. It's a contribution to a project, so I wanted to do as little change as possible. They use a python environment to run the rest and I just needed this variable to exist there instead of system wise.

Comment: If you provide an answer around this i'll select it as the response, as it is what my issue was (basically that you can use read-only vars to write to files but can't set variables).

Comment: I do not understand. `you can use read-only vars to write to files` like, you can _use_ read-only vars to do anything with them, except setting, that's what _read_ - only means.

Comment: Well, given that setting the var in throughout the script was the intent of my change, I either had to change the name of the variable, or change the read-only property.